# How to use Tkinter after method multiple times or is there alternative method for that?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have program that can show webcam image/video on tkinter. I want my program to run method when I press certain key (from keyboard) or button (tkinter button) inside tkinter. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()

label =Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def show_frames():
   cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
   label.imgtk = imgtk
   label.configure(image=imgtk)
   label.after(20, show_frames)

def method():
      print("test")

show_frames()
root.after(2000, method)
root.mainloop()
```

Problem with this code is was that first it ran only once. Then I tried to change the method it in this:

```
def method():
    while True:
      print("test")
```

Problem with this is that it freezes first the window and ultimately crashes the program. Even with only this one print statement.

how would you suggest I go about this? Or is there other method than `after` that I should use instead?

Comment: have you tried `root.after(ms, method)` at the end of the `method` function?

Comment: Also removing the `while True:`? Seems to also crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a key_pressed function and now it handles multiple key presses you can see it yourself on the console.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()

label =Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def show_frames():
   cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
   label.imgtk = imgtk
   label.configure(image=imgtk)
   label.after(20, show_frames)

def key_pressed(event):
    method()

def method():
      print("test")

show_frames()
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```